# QInputDialog::getText makes crash an app with only a system tray icon (with no window)

Tags: qt

When I run this code and quit the Input Dialog, the app quits (so the system tray icon disapears) :

main.cpp

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include <QApplication>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    MainWindow w;
    w.hide();

    return a.exec();
}
```

window.h

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QWidget>
#include <QSystemTrayIcon>

class MainWindow : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    MainWindow();
    ~MainWindow();
    QSystemTrayIcon* sticon;
    QAction* actTexte1;
    QAction* actTexte3;
public slots:
    void changeTexte1();
    void changeTexte3();

};

#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

window.cpp

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include <QSystemTrayIcon>
#include <QWidget>
#include <QMenu>
#include <QtGui>
#include <QApplication>
#include <QInputDialog>

MainWindow::MainWindow()
{
    sticon = new QSystemTrayIcon(this);
    QIcon icon(":/music.png");
    sticon->setIcon(icon);

    QMenu* stmenu = new QMenu(NULL);
    actTexte1 = new QAction("test",NULL);
    actTexte3 = new QAction("exit",NULL);
    stmenu->addAction(actTexte1);
    stmenu->addAction(actTexte3);
    sticon->setContextMenu(stmenu);
    sticon->show();
    connect(actTexte1, SIGNAL(triggered()), this, SLOT(changeTexte1()));
    connect(actTexte3, SIGNAL(triggered()), this, SLOT(changeTexte3()));


}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
}

void MainWindow::changeTexte1()
{
    bool dialogResult;
    QString result = QInputDialog::getText(this, "Echonest API Key", "Enter your API key:", QLineEdit::Normal,
                                           "key", &dialogResult);

}

void MainWindow::changeTexte3()
{
    QApplication::quit();
    exit(1);
}
```

If in the main I set w.show(); instead of w.hide(); it does not crash BUT an empty window appears and I don't want this, I want an only system tray app.
How should I do?

Comment: it's solved with : a.setQuitOnLastWindowClosed(false);

Comment: can you turn your comment into an answer and mark it as 'accepted' to indicate that this question no longer needs an answer?